# Nftables does not work as expected to block with meter

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, nftables

Goal: Account for excess packets whose rate source IP and destination port are greater than 200 packets per second, example:

1s, 2s, 3s ...: IP 1.1.1.1 to MyServer:80 
[This happens 201 times in second 1]

I want to count packets whose transfer rate from the Source IP and Destination Port exceeds 200 packets per second, basically, I will do this only for http (chain below)
But it's not working, see,

`ip saddr 191.185.17.156 counter packets 100 bytes 4920`

`meter http size 65535 { ip saddr . tcp dport limit rate over 200/second } add @blocklist { ip saddr } counter packets 73 bytes 3576`

How is it possible to have in 1.) only 100 registered packets, and in 2.) 73 registered packets, where 100 is less than 200, therefore the counter of 2. should be at zero, as no packet exceeded the rate of 200 packets per second in saddr:dport.

```
table netdev filter {
    set whitelist {
        type ipv4_addr
        elements = { 186.248.79.100 }
    }

    set blocklist {
        type ipv4_addr
        size 65535
        flags dynamic,timeout
        timeout 30s
    }

    chain ingress {
        type filter hook ingress device "eth0" priority -450; policy accept;
        ip saddr @whitelist accept
        ip daddr 10.0.0.192 jump input
        ip daddr != 10.0.0.192 jump forward
    }

    chain http {
        ip saddr 191.185.17.156 counter
        meter http size 65535 { ip saddr . tcp dport limit rate over 200/second } add @blocklist { ip saddr } counter
    }

    chain forward { }

    chain input {
        tcp dport vmap { 8000 : jump portainer, 9443 : jump portainer }
        tcp dport vmap { 80 : jump http }
    }
}
```

I've also tried putting:

`ip saddr 191.185.17.156 meter http size 65535 { ip saddr . tcp dport limit rate over 200/second } add @blocklist { ip saddr } counter`

This is because I thought I might be receiving packets from other IPs, but unfortunately that's not the case.

Comment: cross-posted: https://serverfault.com/questions/1143636/nftables-does-not-work-as-expected-to-block-with-meter . Don't do this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: @A.B Do you believe there could be a bug in nftables?